# Cannot resolve System.Linq namespace

Tags: linq, visual-studio, namespaces, resolve

Working in a standard visual studio 2013 web app, I realized that it seems not possible to resolve the System.Linq namespace, e.g. on

```
mylist.Sum(...)
```

in a class when using System.Linq is missing in the code. You have to add

```
using System.Linq
```

manually, which is possible (references are added to project). What is the reason for this?

Comment: so add reference to it, if not added default

Comment: What do you mean by "missing in the code"? You mean there is no `using` statement?

Comment: What are you using, C# or VB.NET? Why do you expect that `using System.Linq;` is added automatically?

Comment: ReSharper prompts you to include using statements for missing references, however VS won't do this for you out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the LINQ methods are [*extension methods*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). The compiler only knows which extension methods you're interested based on which `using` directives are present in your code, e.g.

```
// Imports extension methods from all static classes in the
// System.Linq namespace
using System.Linq;

// C# 6 only: imports extension methods from System.Linq.Enumerable only
using static System.Linq.Enumerable;
```

That's just how extension methods work... it's not LINQ-specific.